# reduce() object by arraykey is not using the first key javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key, reduce

```
const cliente = {
    nome: "Andre",
    idade: 36,
    cpf: "123.456.789.10",
    email: "andre@gmail.com"
}

const chaves = ["nome", "idade", "cpf", "email"];

const clienteString = chaves.reduce((acum, curr) => acum += curr + ":" + cliente[curr] + ";")
 
console.log(clienteString);
```

the current output is: `**nome**idade:36;cpf:123.456.789.10;email:andre@gmail.com;`

the value of the key "nome:" is not being considered in the string

it should output this: `nome:Andre;idade:36;cpf:123.456.789-10;email:andre@gmail.com;`

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, please consider accepting an answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler version that does what you want:

```js
const cliente = {
  nome: "Andre",
  idade: 36,
  cpf: "123.456.789.10",
  email: "andre@gmail.com",
};

console.log(
  Object.entries(cliente)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${key}:${value};`)
    .join("")
);
```

`Object.entries` returns an array of `["key", "value"]`. Then we `map` over that and turn it into an array of `"key:value;"`. Then we `join` the array of `"key:value;"` into a string.